# Git Forked Workflow: How do I work as a developer and the integration manager under one account?

Tags: git, github, version-control, workflow, git-fork

#### Background

I am currently working on an open source project on GitHub that is using a forked/integration-manager workflow. I own the blessed repo and other developers have been working on their own forks. I am working as the integration-manager, but also as a developer (the main one actually).

#### The problem

I am using the blessed repo as if it is a forked developer repo, e.g. pushing unfinished work there for backups and having several feature branches on the go. This is rather messy! The blessed repo is supposed to only contain complete features and be neat, tidy etc. Other devs have complained about this when they want to fork from the blessed repo.

#### What I would like

Ideally, I would like another repo that I could use, under the same account, that is my developer repo and then I merge my changes via a pull request as other developers would.

However, you cannot fork your own repo on GitHub! I have seen ways around this by creating another repo from scratch and then setting the blessed one as the upstream repo, but I don't think this repo would then be included in the network map and be a true fork, so isn't what I really want.

Another idea I had would be to create a second account, so I would have one dev and one manager account, but that's a pain.

Is there anyway I can get my ideal setup with having to use the two methods covered above? Seems to me this would be a fairly popular thing, however I haven't found much online specific to this problem. Any advice on an alternative but similar approach would also be appreciated. I'd quite like to stick to this workflow and will probably end up making another account if I have to, but I'm open to suggestions.

Here is the repo for reference: https://github.com/DaBigJoe/ObsidianSuite

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems my research wasn't extensive enough prior to asking the question...

I had never heard of GitHub's organisations, which allowed me to do exactly what I wanted. I created a new organisation for this specific project, and transferred ownership of the repo to the new organisation. I am the only person in the organisation, so I have control over the main (original) repo, now ObsidianSuite/ObsidianSuite, allowing me to act as the integration manager. I can now also fork the repo into DaBigJoe/ObsidianSuite (the original name), to act as a developer!

Sorted.

Thanks for all the answers/comments given!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to commit your unfinished work locally, this can also record your change (excepte your PC is damaged). This is enough, if you work usually can be finished in short period. When you finish your work, then you can push it to github.

If you still need to back up your work in network or your work usually finished for a long time, you can create a repo (such as with same account on github) for temporary use:

```
git remote add temp <URL for the new repo>
git push -u temp branchname
```

If your local work is finished, you can direct push to your main repo.

Comment: That works, however that temp repo wouldn't appear in the network of the main repo. I would quite like the changes pushed to it to appear on the network graph in the same way they do for the other devs, so that people can see what I'm working on.

Comment: Push to temp repo is only for you unfinished a work but want to backup it in remote repo. If you are ready to push your finished work, you can direct push to your main repo.